Is the irrealis 'were' used in the dependent clauses of conditionals?
I'm already aware that directly inside of an if-clause, it is common to use the irrealis 'were.' Take the following sentence for example:

If he were taller, he might walk faster.

My question is about what happens in the main clause. Usually, I see a modal such as 'would,' 'could,' or 'might' modifying the main verb here, but sometimes I see sentences with an additional dependent clause containing a preterite verb:

If he were taller, he might walk in a way that was faster.

My intuition says that this is ungrammatical and the bolded verb should also match the irrealis mood of the rest of the sentence:

If he were taller, he might walk in a way that were faster.

As I understand it, the sentence is tenseless, so it wouldn't make sense to use the preterite here, but grammar-checking software doesn't agree with me nor have I seen what I'm thinking of in writing (though I haven't been looking for very long).
I also have seen a conditional modal used a second time, but that feels unwieldy to me albeit grammatical:

If he were taller, he might walk in a way that would be faster.

What is prescribed in a case like this? What do people actually say/write? Would someone hear/read any of these sentences and think something were off?
EDIT: As @FumbleFingers pointed out, a sentence needn't start with an if-statement to have a conditional clause. A sentence targeting the grammatical feature in question could just as easily be written

He might walk in a way that was/were faster.

I might also add that I realize that this sentence is a little unwieldy; not many would say/write 'in a way that was/were' because it's quite frankly unnecessary. However dependent clauses in conditionals do come up. A more natural example might be:

I would walk on the sidewalk that was/were in the shade.

Note that the case I'm considering is that in which 'would' signals the conditional, not the past tense.

I'm not sure the presence or absence of initial subjunctive If X were [true] ever makes any difference to the syntax of the following (always, "conditional") statement.

The modal caters for the signalling of the hypothetical; 'were' / 'would be' are unnecessary (and 'were' at least is unacceptable). // Note that 'If he were/was taller, he would walk faster' is also acceptable, and is less hedged (it rides roughshod over an element of uncertainty).

@FumbleFingers Yeah, good catch, I think you're right. I was all caught up on this one sentence the way I'd heard it and I didn't think to dissect it.

@EdwinAshworth Thanks for the comment! One question though: I don't quite understand what you mean in your note. Are you referring to the usage of 'was' vs. 'were' in the if-statement, or are you commenting on the usage of 'might' in the conditional?

A simple perspective is that once you've set your sentence up with "If he were taller, he might," you are set. One if and one were does the trick.

The was/were choice is a separate issue; I was just adding the additional point that the indicative is often used in such situations, especially in the UK.

I think you can even use the simple present: "he might walk in a way that is faster."
